Carrier concentration and quasi-neutrality in non-uniformly doped semiconductor
A excerpt regarding non uniform doping from Semiconductor Physics and Devices by Neamen, 4th ed

I could not make sense of the following

"When equilibrium is reached, the mobile carrier concentration
is not exactly equal to the fixed impurity concentration and the induced electric field
prevents any further separation of charge. In most cases of interest, the space charge
induced by this diffusion process is a small fraction of the impurity concentration,
thus the mobile carrier concentration is not too different from the impurity dopant
density."

An explanation for the above would be appreciated! (for example: is the concentration of mobile carrier not equal to fixed impurity due to Electron Hole Pair generation in response to temperature like in uniformly doped semiconductor or is it somehow different due to diffusion's effect also)
Suppose we dope electrons whose concentration varies with distance as n(x) and the donor impurity concentration varies with distance as Nd(x). Once doped, these donor atoms would be fixed in place, hence fixing Nd(x). My other questions are that
If we have n(x) at t=0  (before diffusion current and hence drift current was set up). Will n(x) at equilibrium = n(x) at t=0? or will it be constant, or will it be different from the mentioned cases.
Also is n(x) at t=0 or/and n(x) at equilibrium same(or almost same) as concentration distribution of dopant wrt x: Nd(x)?
Also at last in this image, "quasi" charge neutrality is mentioned,so why not a strict equality? Plus why should it be valid here, shouldn't diffusion and drift change carrier concentration n(x) profile from the doping profile Nd(x) such that neutrality isn't held at every small region?

What is "EHP generation"?
The charge polarization is mainly due to diffusion.  If you have non-uniform dopant concentration but exact charge neutrality, electrons (assuming you dope electrons) feel zero electric field but have a non-uniform concentration.  So you would have net electron flow toward the low-density region.  Moving away from true neutrality, there is now an electric field opposing the flow due to charge accumulation.  Eventually the diffusive force and electrostatic force cancel each other out and you get equilibrium.
Remember how you get a contact potential when different metals are put together?  Same thing.

By EHP I meant electron hole pair (now edited), your answers clears the way in which equilibrium is reached, but it doesnt addresses my question that why the electron concentration (we are doping electrons) is not exactly equal to donor concentration. Is it because of EHP generation due to temperature like in uniformly doped substance (so we can say electron conc almost equals donor conc if donor conc is much greater than electrons generated by temp), or is it not exactly equal due to this new diffusion phenomenon that didn't occur in uniformly doped. Also please address my additional question

Extra electrons carried by the dopant atoms are thermally excited into the conduction band, and this is never 100% (Boltzmann statistics!).  So you always have fewer doped electrons than dopant atoms.  Nothing to do with particle-hole per se, because the hole band isn't involved.  As for the additional questions, if you think about the physical picture, you know the answer is no to every question.

But the last line in the photo states that given quasi-neutrality is followed then n0(x) approximately equals Nd(x)

That last line very specifically tells you that they are unequal.

if by equal we consider approximately also, then it holds? If so, why should quasi-neutrality hold here

The approximation obviously can't always be valid.  You have the expression.  Why don't you try to find out the necessary condition for the two sides to be almost equal?
